# spring config server unable to find local git repository when directory name is different

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config-server

I have a config store repository `http://gitea-server:3000/demoadmin/demo-school-config-store.git`.
That repository is cloned and synced in a directory **`config-store`**. *Please note git repository name is different than directory name*
And my config server application is like this:

```yaml
spring:
  application.name: config-server
  output.ansi.enabled: ALWAYS
  cloud.config.server.git:
    search-paths: '{application}'
    uri: file://${user.home}/source/demo-school-config-store
```

Now when I try to check my config server by fetching config with following url:

```
http://localhost:8312/teacher-service/local
```

It gives me following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No directory at file:///Users/mafzal/source/demo-school-config-store
```

After doing lot of debugging I found that when I rename directory to `demo-school-config-store`, everything works well.

Is there a way to make config server run with local config repository having different directory name than it's repository name?

Answer (score 0):

https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/multi/multi__spring_cloud_config_server.html :

> 2.1.2 Version Control Backend Filesystem Use

> With VCS-based backends (git, svn), files are checked out or cloned to the local filesystem. By default, they are put in the system temporary directory with a prefix of `config-repo-`. On linux, for example, it could be `/tmp/config-repo-<randomid>`. Some operating systems routinely clean out temporary directories. This can lead to unexpected behavior, such as missing properties.
> To avoid this problem, change the directory that Config Server uses by setting **spring.cloud.config.server.git.basedir** or spring.cloud.config.server.svn.basedir to a directory that does not reside in the system temp structure.

As for the `searchPaths` :

> Every repository can also optionally store config files in **sub-directories**, and patterns to search for those directories can be specified as `searchPaths`.

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/config-repo
          searchPaths: foo,bar*
```

> In the preceding example, the server searches for config files in the top level and in the **`foo/` sub-directory and also any sub-directory whose name begins with `bar`**.

---

UPDATE:

I missed the part that the config server git backend is configured to get the configuration from the *local* repository, not the remote one you specified. If you want it to retrieve configuration from the **config-store** directory, then just clone your repo to `${user.home}/source/config-store` instead (or rename the existing `${user.home}/source/demo-school-config-store` directory) and use that in the config server configuration:

```yaml
spring:
  cloud.config.server.git:
   uri: file://${user.home}/source/config-store
```

Comment: That is not what I am asking dekkard. when directory name in which I cloned my repository is different, config server is unable to recognize it.